# spark giving requirement failed: Literal must have a corresponding value to string, but class String found

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I have a spark 2.4.6 with dataframe write as

```
df
  .select((struct(df.columns.map(column): _*)).alias("value"))
  .write
  .format("kafka")
  .options(........)
  .save
```

But after making a jar and doing spark submit in version 3.0.2 it gives:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Literal must have a corresponding value to string, but class String found.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.validateLiteralValue(literals.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal.<init>(literals.scala:292)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$.$anonfun$validateQuery$2(KafkaWriter.scala:55)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$.validateQuery(KafkaWriter.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$.write(KafkaWriter.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.createRelation(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:962)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:962)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:398)
    at part4integrations.IntegratingKafka$.nimbleWrite(IntegratingKafka.scala:145)
    at part4integrations.IntegratingKafka$.main(IntegratingKafka.scala:154)
    at part4integrations.IntegratingKafka.main(IntegratingKafka.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:928)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

On checking the functions

we have that validation function in 3.0.2
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/648457905c4ea7d00e3d88048c63f360045f0714/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/literals.scala#L292

but not in the previous version
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.6/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/literals.scala

Is there any resolution to this without upgrading the spark version?

 as rebuilding the jar with version 3.0.2 works fine.

Comment: Seems the writer only accepts string. Can you try `.select((struct(df.columns.map(column): _*)).cast("string").alias("value"))`?

Comment: it seems it is behaving the same way @mck

Comment: If you are trying to send the event to a kafka topic - you can try this way -> `df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)").as[(String, String)]`

If you are creating json - then you can try this way -> `CAST(key as STRING) as key , to_json(struct(*)) AS value`